Think creatively and prove
Doing some Lateral Thinking can you prove

19 = 7
Hint

 Involves Roman Numerals


"Think creatively" in puzzling.se is not very compatible with hints. Prepare to be amazed.

We know that multiplying a number by 1 gives the same number.

 

Well, the above equation is not true.
But if you change your perspective...

 

..it is indeed true, beacuse

 LXI is 61 in roman numerals.


Since this involves Roman Numerals (according to the hint)

19 in Roman numerals is XIX.

However, in the font that Stack Exchange uses, we have that

There are 4 lines in the 2 Xs, and another 3 in the I.

So 19=7 in this case because

We are counting the number of lines used in the number when in Roman Numerals.

We also have (something that I noticed after figuring the answer):

that 21 also is equal to 7 here. (XXI, which also has 7 lines)


Also note that the last spoiler is just a cool little thing I noticed right after getting the answer, nothing else other than that.

Is this creative enough?

 One Nine = 7 characters

